# Camel - Handle Exception inside Split and continue

Tags: java, exception, split, apache-camel

In my camel route I have a simple split like this

```
                .split(body(), eventListAggregationStrategy).parallelProcessing()
                    .process(rawEventTransformationProcessor)
                .end()
```

If exceptions occure inside `.process(rawEventTransformationProcessor)` I want them to be handled and send to an error queue. However all my attempts failed and the whole route stopped.
I tried onException in multiple ways (with handled, continue, shareUnitOfWork) and so on.

```
        onException(RawEventTransformationException.class)
                .to("log:RawEventTransformationException?showAll=true&multiline=true&level=ERROR")
                .handled(true)
                .process(exchange -> {
                    RawEventTransformationException cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, RawEventTransformationException.class);
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(cause.getFailedEvent());
                })
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, RawEvent.class)
                .to("rabbitmq://errors?queue=transformed-data-fails&routingKey=transformed-data-fails&autoDelete=false");
```

What works if I have an additional `direct` route that I trigger from inside the Processor when an Exception works.

```
catch (RawEventTransformationException e1) {
            producerTemplate.sendBody(e1);
            exchange.getIn().setBody(List.of());
            throw e1;
        }
```

What is the best practice way in catching this exception and letting the rest continue?

Comment: If you want to send error message to specific queue you can configure dead letter channel: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/eips/dead-letter-channel.html

Answer (score 1):

You can have your EventListAggregationStrategy clear the exception on the exchange it returns:

```
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    ...
    newExchange.setException(null);
    return newExchange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using route-level exception handling with `continued(true)` worked fine for me at least. All messages split messages got processed and exception handled. Checkout [Dead Letter channel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/dead-letter-channel.html) for information about sending failed exchanges to error queue.

You could also call direct route inside the split block and use route-level exception handling there to limit the exception handling to just split messages.

```java
public class ExampleTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {

        List<String> body = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b", "exception", "c", "d"});
        template.sendBody("direct:start", body);
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
             
                from("direct:start")
                    .onException(Exception.class)
                        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Exception handled: ${exception.message}")
                        .continued(true)
                    .end()
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Start")
                    .split(body()).parallelProcessing()
                        .choice()
                            .when(body().isNotEqualTo("exception"))
                                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${body}")
                            .otherwise()
                                .process(exchange -> {
                                    throw new Exception("Example exception");
                                })
                        .end()
                    .end()
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Done");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

logs:

```
INFO  [log]         org.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger : Start
INFO  [log]         org.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger : b
INFO  [log]         org.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger : a
INFO  [log]         org.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger : c
INFO  [log]         org.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger : d
ERROR [log]         org.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger : Exception handled: Example exception
INFO  [log]         org.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger : Done
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. As soon as an expcetion occurs the split stops. I will try it with a deadletter queue.

Comment: You can also try moving the logic inside split to a separate direct route and using route-level exception handling there. i.e `.split(body()).parallelProcessing().to("direct:handleSplitMessage").end()`.